# custom format in numeral.js negative number (-20) to be 20(-)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, numeral.js

I use the [numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com) library

I am interested in Do [custom format](http://numeraljs.com/#custom-formats)
That wherever there is a negative number (like - 20) the library will show it to me so 20 (-)

I need the minus sign to be in parentheses

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something similar to this

```js
numeral.register('format', 'negative', {
    regexps: {
        format: /(-)/,
        unformat: /(-)/
    },
    format: function(value, format, roundingFunction) {
        return value < 0 ? -value + " (-)" : value;
    },
    unformat: function(s) {
        return s.endsWith(" (-)") ? -parseInt(s.substr(0, s.length - 4)) : parseInt(s);
    }
});

// use your custom format
const result = numeral(-5).format('(-)');
const unresult = numeral(result).format();
console.log(result)
console.log(unresult)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply,
If I want it to be so by default?

Comment: does it have to support other formats alongside the negative one?

Comment: is there really a need to use `numeral.js` library if you are not using any of it's features?

Comment: I use  defaultFormat as  Numeral.defaultFormat('0,0[.][00] $');
no custemFormat other

Comment: I need it to get me back in this format   '0,0[.][00] $')(-)'
is it possible?